# How get device rotation in lenovo A3000?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

Salaam. I get data from my gyro in android 4.2 in my samsung device, but get nothing in lenovo a3000, 
in samsung i have rotation in front of my textviews, but in lenovo i haven't anything, even zero. it is empty.
How should i read rotation (roll, pitch, Heading) in Lenovo A3000? 
my code is below:

```
public class CalculateDataService extends Service{

final static String TAG = "Roshan java";    
SensorManager sensorManager;

private int currentDataIndex = 0;

int orientationSensor;
float headingAngle;
float pitchAngle;
float rollAngle;

LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude;
double longitude;
double altitude;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2, locationListener);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    orientationSensor = Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION;

    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(orientationSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

}

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        altitude = location.getAltitude();

        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
        Log.d(TAG, "Longitude: " + String.valueOf(longitude));
        Log.d(TAG, "Altitude: " + String.valueOf(altitude));
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
};

final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
        {
            headingAngle = sensorEvent.values[0];
            pitchAngle = sensorEvent.values[1];
            rollAngle = sensorEvent.values[2];

            Log.d(TAG, "Heading: " + String.valueOf(headingAngle));
            Log.d(TAG, "Pitch: " + String.valueOf(pitchAngle));
            Log.d(TAG, "Roll: " + String.valueOf(rollAngle));

            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/roshan");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(
                        currentDataIndex+","+
                        makePrecision2(rollAngle)+","+
                        makePrecision2(pitchAngle)+","+
                        makePrecision2(headingAngle)+","+
                        latitude+","+
                        longitude+","+
                        altitude
                        );
                currentDataIndex++;
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor senor, int accuracy) {
        //Not used
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
      locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
      sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private float makePrecision2(float input){
    return ((float)((int)(input*100f)))/100f;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sou May should use getRotation() or getOrientation() both report the same values:

•0 (default, portrait),

•1 (device 90 degree counterclockwise),

•3 (device 90 degree clockwise)

It does not report when you put it "on its head" (rotate 180, that would be the value 2). This result is possibly device-specific.

First of all you should make clear if you use an emulator or a device. Do you know how to rotate the emulator? Then I would recommend to create a small test program with a onCreate() Method like this:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

Log.d("ORIENTATION_TEST", "getOrientation(): " + mDisplay.getOrientation());
}
```

Check if the screen of your your device has been locked in the device settings Settings > Display > Auto-Rotate Screen. If that checkbox is unchecked, Android will not report orientation changes to your Activity. To be clear: it will not restart the activity. In my case I get only 0, like you described.

You can check this from your program if you add these lines to onCreate()

```
int sysAutoRotate = 0;
try {
    sysAutoRotate = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION);
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Log.d("ORIENTATION_TEST", "Auto-rotate Screen from Device Settings:" + sysAutoRotate);

It will return 0 if Auto-Rotate is off and 1 if Auto-Rotate is on. Another try. In your original program you might have set in manifest
android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: thank you man, but I need roll, pitch and heading angle of the device. like [this](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/Images/rotations.gif)

Comment: Why do you use the TYPE_ORIENTATION instead of TYPE_GYROSCOPE ? 
-> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

Comment: my device doesn't have gyroscope sensor.

Comment: But are you sure it could sense the orientation?